# Highlight cells that only contain letters

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

How do I use conditional formatting in excel to only highlight alphanumerical strings that contains alphabetical characters only. So a string might have:

- 142425aasj
- 424252 asd
- asdasd 65566
- 21123123
- 123123123
- 222

It will only highlight the first 3 lines.

Much appreciated

Comment: Why was this closed? Just because it's not a code question doesn't mean it should be closed. If anything, it could be moved to the superuser site

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ISNUMBER` function to achieve this: Simply use this as the custom formula:

```
=NOT(ISNUMBER(A1))
```

To apply this formula, select cell A1 and after that the full column A (adjust to your column). Then go to *Conditional Formatting*->*New Rule*->*Use a formula to determine which cells to format*. Here, insert the aove formula and set you format.

Done!

In case your numbers are stored as text, use this formula instead:

```
=ISERROR(VALUE(A1))
```

Comment: It should highlight the first 3 lines....how ???

Comment: This assumes his numbers are saved as numbers.  If they're saved as strings then ISNUMBER will return FALSE.  You should use =NOT(VALUE(ISNUMBER(A1)))

Comment: @user2063626: I updated the answer, explaining how to apply the formula.

Comment: @Jesse: Good point regarding numbers stored as text, thanks! However, note that your formula would not work, as ISNUMBER will always return FALSE for texts. I updated the answer with this formula: `=ISERROR(VALUE(A1))`

Comment: Doh!  Of course, I had it backward.

Comment: Thanks guys. The formula did not fully work as it highlight numbers with spaces in between.

Comment: Try `=ISERROR(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")))`